# How can I automate getting an access token from Slack?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, slack-api, apigee

I want to make an alert system on Apigee that will automatically send alerts to Slack, without the need for human interference.

However, the only OAuth flow for Slack I found on their api site seems to require a user to manually input their credentials: https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth

How can I automate getting an access token from Slack, so without having to manually input credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood the concept of Oauth. The way it is supposed to work is, that you run the process only once per Slack team (usually while installing the Slack app to your Slack team) and then store the access token you received for future reference (e.g. in a database). So whenever your Slack app needs the access token after installation it can always reuse the one it received during installation.

If you don't require any scripts to run for installation and you only need the access token you can also install your Slack app directly from Slack (under "Your Apps") and then copy and paste the resulting access token to your app configuration. Check [this](https://api.slack.com/internal-integrations) documentation for further information.

Comment: I do not think this question is unreasonable. Our team is deep into infrastructure as a service, and Slack is integral part of our automation chain. Our goal is to have our software set up and configure everything. We would place the Slack account credentials in the vault and have our automation interact with Slack servers to generate the access token without further human interaction. This becomes especially important when spinning up multiple instances. So I would say, someone please actually answer the original question.

Comment: From what I understand you have a different set of requirements than the original author of this question. So I would think its would be more helpful if you would just ask your own question?

Comment: The requirements are the same, the rationale is different

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating webhooks on the fly, it requires OAuth 2.0 each time. However, if you use the Web API chat.postMessage method, it only requires the token (under the OAuth & Permissions section) to make a HTTP POST request to send a notification.